# PhpMyAdmin duplicate entry for key primary

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci NOT NULL,
  `horsepower` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `weight` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `yearofprod` int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_hungarian_ci;

INSERT INTO `cars` (`id`, `name`, `horsepower`, `weight`, `yearofprod`) VALUES
(1, 'Mazda', 200, 1000, 1987);


ALTER TABLE `cars`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `cars`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;
```

I have this code in sql and if I try to insert something it drops me the duplicate entry for key primary. Can someone help me to fix it? I tried a few things that were on the internet but nothing worked so far. I have to solve this problem till tomorrow so I have to be fast with it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the  `INSERT` statement to the end of that code (after `id` is already defined as primary key and auto-incrementing) and simply *don't* include an ID in the INSERT statement (it will be set automatically)